# How to set rjsx mode for every js file in Spacemacs?

Tags: reactjs, emacs, spacemacs

I've already tried putting `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . rjsx-mode))` in `dotspacemacs/user-config` but js files are not opening with rjsx mode.
And yes, i've already tried reloading `init.el` and fully closing spacemacs.